# Excel--SUMPRODUCTIF? Work around?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table, excel-2013

I am trying to calculate how many class registrations my company has received per month, per year. ]

So far, I've been able to do this using `SUMPRODUCT`, (for example:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATE(YEAR($A$2:$A$10),MONTH($A$2:$A$10),1)=DATE(2013,1,1))))`

but it is a lot and I'm hoping there's an easier way.

I have about 16,000 Registrations total to sort through with registration dates ranging from 2003 to 2014. Each registration has the following info:

> the Registration Date, Course Name, Class Date, Name, Title, Company, City, State, Type, and Paid.

What I really want to be able to do now is show how many class registrations we received per month, per year but separate it out for both private and public types. I have not figured out how to do this yet.

Please help!

*I tried to include an image of part of my current excel spreadsheet, but it said the site told me I need "at least 10 reputation to post images"*

Comment: Use a pivot table. It will give you much simpler data readability, when you add in filters and slicers. And allow very easy editing of the data in the future.

Comment: I've never used a pivot table. Any advice on how I should set it up?

Answer (score 5):

You can still use `SUMPRODUCT`.

You could use the following:

`=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A1:A3)=2013) * (MONTH(A1:A3)=1) * (F1:F3 = "Private") * 1)`

And:

`=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A1:A3)=2013) * (MONTH(A1:A3)=1) * (F1:F3 = "Public") * 1)`

Where `A1:A3` is the range that has your dates and `F1:F3` is your flag that denotes public or private courses.
You can also alter the formula to:

`=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A1:A3)=YEAR(G3)) * (MONTH(A1:A3)=MONTH(G3)) * (F1:F3 = "Private") * 1)`

Where Cell `G3` is any day in the month/year you want to calculate for.

Comment: +1 but no real need for *1 at the end when using * to multiply the conditions

Comment: You are correct about the *1, however, I sometimes find, when using large formulae, I sometimes get errors.  Adding the * 1 just ensures it returns a count of the entities that qualify.